# Существует ли возможность отслеживать изменения объекта в Dart 2.0+?

Tags: flutter, dart

Пытаюсь разрабатывать приложения через фреймворк Flutter и вот познакомился с StatefulWidget, теперь завис на нем. Не понимаю как правильно синхронизировать изменение целевой внешней коллекции с изменениями, которые должны происходить через State. Мою задачу выполнить можно и без использования стейтфул виджета, но хочется все сделать красиво и удобно.

Вопрос заключается в том, могу ли я подключить какой-то Observer к нужному объекту, для отслеживания его изменений? Я рылся в инглиш версии стак оверфлоу и нашел только решение для версии Dart ниже 2. Там есть нужная библиотека, но вот решения для своего проекта я так и не нашел. Попытался написать что-то сам, но моих знаний не хватило на то, чтобы понять как отследить присваивание объекта: пытался переделать класс List под свои нужды, но переписать оператор "=" нельзя, вроде как, и это стало для меня стеной.

Помогите понять как мне быть с этим. Код не вижу смысла сюда крепить так как интересует только способ решения задачи, а не ее практическое решение.

Comment: Какие изменения вы собрались отслеживать то? И приложите код, желательно на [DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/?null_safety=true) чтоб понять что вы хотите.

Comment: Предположим, у меня есть коллекция картинок, которые сами по себе имеют поля адреса на источник, название и другое. Коллекция с ними постоянно будет обновляться и в конец будут добавляться новые элементы, а с начала будут удаляться лишние для оптимизации памяти. Загрузка будет происходить по мере приближения скроллинга GridView ко дну. В итоге измения должны отслеживаться как для элементов коллекции (для карточек внутри GridView) так и для самого GridView(количество элементов, индексы).

Comment: Хотя, для элементов внутри GridView вообще нежелателен State в таком случае, но вот у меня задача посложнее и требует, чтобы даже там он был для поддержания актуальной информации.

Comment: Так вы же сами будете манипулировать элементами внутри GridView. Вот и отслеживайте их состояние. И ещё раз, приведите код.

Comment: Способов несколько (из встроенных, без зависимостей - чистые стримы и ChangeNotifier/ValueNotifier). Класс стейтфулвиджета же, вообще только к виджетам применяется (по самому назначению), а не к произвольным объектам...

Comment: Оператор "=" переопределить можно, гугли

Answer (score 1):

Особенностью разработки сложного проекта на Flutter, на мой взгляд заключается в выборе Архитектуры (или проще говоря паттерна программирования)
Вначале выбери что тебе ближе/либо больше подходит к конкретному проекту: MVC, MVVM, Flux, Redux, BLoC

В каждом варианте, по разному решается проблема оповещения при изменении state. Одни используют проброс callback-функции, другие подписку на stream-ы, и т.д.
Думаю лучше с самого начала посмотреть как это делается правильно, и уже исходя из этого принять решение для своего проекта.

Comment: Как вы интересно смешали архитектурные паттерны и стейт менеджеры...